# Highlighting two rows in table

Tags: html, html-table, row, highlight

Suppose, that we have a HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table tr:hover td {
                background-color: #aaaaaa;
            }

            table tr:hover + tr td[colspan] {
                background-color: #aaaaaa;          
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width: 100%" border=1>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">One</td>
              <td>Two</td>
              <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">Four</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">One</td>
              <td>Two</td>
              <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">Four</td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/YEXjq/

If user places the mouse cursor on first row of the double-row configuration, both "inner" rows are highlighted. But if he places cursor on the second row, only the second one is highlighted (check the example if the description is not clear enough).

Is there a way to modify the CSS such that in the latter case both rows will be highlighted?

Comment: Guess you have to use JS like mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843796/how-to-deal-with-rowspan-and-background-colors-within-a-table)

Comment: Why dont you just highlight the entire table with background colour, on hovering on table . like this,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ymK2H/1/ . im not sure sure if its feasible solution, but i felt its easy and simple

Comment: @dreamweiver: Maybe the user has other rows where he just wants to highlight that specific row (and it has no `rowspan`)

Comment: @harry, seems valid enough, if Jquery is an option, then i can give it a try spook

Comment: @dreamweiver I didn't wrote that, because I thought, that's obvious - there are multiple rows designed like that and that's why highlighting the whole table does not solve the problem :) I'll modify my question to reflect that.

Comment: @dreamweiver I'll use javascript if there is no other option, I kinda hoped, that it can be solved purely by CSS :) There's also another solution - to embed each row in inner table and then highlight that table, but it seems like an overkill to me :)

Comment: @Spook:That logic would be very heavy,in terms of LOC. let me try in jQuery